# How many ways to select distinct pairs from k disjoint sets

Tags: combinatorics

How many pairs can be generated from k disjoint sets. For example I have following 3 sets(k=3):

A = {1,2,3} B = {4,5} C = {6,7}

I want to form pairs such there's no element of pair coming from the same set.

In this case I can create 16 = |A|x|B| + |A|x|C| + |B|x|C| (multiplication and summation rule of combinatorics)

I can compute it on computer but I'm wondering is there a closed formula for that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose that we have $n$ groups, of sizes $a_1$ to $a_n$. Except when $n$ is smallish, the following formula for the number $N$ of ways to choose a pair of people from different groups is more efficient:
$$N=\frac{1}{2}\left((a_1+\cdots +a_n)^2 -(a_1^2+\cdots +a_n^2)\right).$$
To see that the formula does the job, expand $(a_1+\cdots +a_n)^2$.

Comment: Thanks for closed formula! Just wondering how did you come up with it?

Comment: The identity $2\sum_{i\lt j}x_ix_j=(x_1+\cdots +x^n)^2-(x_1^2+\cdots+x_n^2)$ comes up pretty often, particularly in Statistics. It is a generalization to $n$ variables of the familiar $2xy=(x+y)^2-(x^2+y^2)$. What I gave is not really a closed form, since it still involves $\sum$. Note that for $n=3$ your way is more efficient. But for example when $n=100$, the formula I suggested is far more efficient.

Comment: If you are interested in more elaborate identities of this type, look for *elementary symmetric functions*.

Comment: You are welcome.